# How to echo out the first term only within get_terms

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy-terms

Wondering if you could help fix my code below. I am trying to echo out the first category taxonomy only from the first post of the author.

I think I'm nearly there. I can get it to output all category titles but the issue in my code is where I am trying to output the first category only.

```
<?php

$args = array(
    'author' => intval(bp_displayed_user_id()),
    'post_type' => 'job_listing'
);

$listings_of_author = get_posts($args);
$postid = $listings_of_author[0]->ID;
$term_list = wp_get_post_terms($postid, 'job_listing_category', true);
$firstTerm = $terms_list[0];

if (get_the_terms($author, 'job_listing_category', true)) {
    echo $fistTerm->name;
}

?>
```

Many thanks for your help.

Matt

Comment: You initially had `echo $fistTerm ->name`, with a space between `$firstTerm` and name. I assume this was just a formatting bug. During formatting correction, this got automatically corrected, though please note that you must *not* have a space there if you do.

Comment: Thanks obsidian, it is indeed a formatting bug which I have corrected. Unfortunately the code itself still doesn't output the first term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several typos which would prevent this from working properly:

```
$term_list = wp_get_post_terms($postid, 'job_listing_category', true);
$firstTerm = $term*s*_list[0]; //should be term_list
```

...later...

```
echo $fistTerm->name; //should be firstTerm
```

Comment: Thank you IarsAnders - lesson to self to check for simple typo errors. It now works perfectly.